# Use global namespace in context on my namespace?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have 2 controllers

```
 /admin/UserController.php

 /front/UserController.php
```

I've marked them with namespaces `admin` and `front`, but now the problem is that I can't reach the other framework classes, I have to put on every class invoke `new \MyClass`, is there a way to access all the global classes, but except the another UserController? in other words make a UserController invisible for each other is that possible?, using laravel-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found it!

```
use \App\Models
use \BaseController
```

I've just needed to specify the classes of the framework I will use, then the problem is gone, thanks!